# Create deep hash mapping in perl

Tags: perl, hash, perl-data-structures

Below is my Code with the Hash

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use JSON::PP; # Just 'use JSON;' on most systems
my %name = (
          'sl' => {
                    'fsd' => {
                               'conf' => {
                                           'ul' => '/sl/fsd/conf/ul',
                                           'si' => '/sl/fsd/conf/si',
                                           'ho1' => '/sl/fsd/conf/ho1'
                                         }
                             }
                  },
          're' => {
                    'fsd' => {
                               'cron' => {
                                           'README' => '/re/fsd/cron/README'
                                         },
                               'bin' => {
                                          'db' => {
                                                    'smart.p_add_tag' => '/re/fsd/bin/db/smart.p_add_tag',
                                                    'smart.p_tag_partition' => '/re/fsd/bin/db/smart.p_tag_partition',
                                                    'smart.p_add_tag_type' => '/re/fsd/bin/db/smart.p_add_tag_type'
                                                  }
                                        },
                               'doc' => {
                                          'SMART' => '/re/fsd/doc/SMART',
                                          'README' => '/re/fsd/doc/README'
                                        },
                               'data' => {
                                           'README' => '/re/fsd/data/README'
                                         },
                               'conf' => {
                                           'al1' => '/re/fsd/conf/al1',
                                           'file' => '/re/fsd/conf/file',
                                           'ho' => '/re/fsd/conf/ho',
                                           'al3' => '/re/fsd/conf/al3',
                                           'hst' => '/re/fsd/conf/hst',
                                           'us' => '/re/fsd/conf/us',
                                           'README' => '/re/fsd/conf/README',
                                           'al2' => '/re/fsd/conf/al2'
                                         }
                             }
                  }
        );




(my $root) = keys %name;

my %nodes = ();
my %tree  = ();
my @queue = ($root);

list_children(\%name, \@queue, \%nodes) while @queue;

my $tree = build_tree($root, \%nodes);

my $json = JSON::PP->new->pretty; # prettify for human consumption

print $json->encode($tree);

sub list_children {
  my $adjac = shift;
  my $queue  = shift;
  my $nodes  = shift;

  my $node = shift @$queue;

  my @children = keys %{$adjac->{$node}};

  @children = grep { ! exists $nodes->{$_}} @children;

  $nodes->{$node} = \@children;

  push @$queue, @children;
}

sub build_tree {
  my $root  = shift;
  my $nodes = shift;

  my @children;
  for my $child (@{$nodes->{$root}}) {
    push @children, build_tree($child, $nodes);
  }

  my %h = ('text'     => $root,
           'children' => \@children);

  return \%h;
}
```

I'm trying to output JSONified hash, but it is only traversing upto two levels. whereas i need it to traverse all upto the last child node of each parent. Can someone please help to achieve this.

Below is current output

```
{
   "text" : "sl",
   "children" : [
      {
         "text" : "fsd",
         "children" : []
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? If you post some code and the result you get when running that code, you will get more help. Just asking 'give me the solution' is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks Paul for your advise.
I tried to traverse through the hash and then assign each second level element as child but it is not working as expected and i'm out of ideas on assign a hash to a hash. Please help.

Comment: The expected output is not what you think. Try Data::Dumper and dump the value - a hash cannot have several keys of the same name.

Comment: Are you trying to create a graph?

Comment: @Zaid No , I'm not creating a graph. I want the output to be JSONified so that i can show a treeview of the hash in web.

Comment: @choroba , my hash does not have several keys of same name in same level, instead they have same name but in different levels.

Comment: @rahulsagar: Negative. `text => 'fruits'` is a sibling of `text => 'Vegetables'`. `'text' eq 'text'`.

Comment: Hi @rahulsagar, you can post the actual code with the problem description above so people can help you debug it easier.

Comment: @Carlisle Have posted my code and expected result

Comment: You posted the code and the expected result, but you didn't post the actual result that you got.  We need to see all three.

Comment: @AndyLester theoutput i posted is the actual result right now and i expect it to drill down more to the last child node.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, transforming the hash, and *then* json-ing is not the most efficient idea, because you're going to make one traversal to transform the hash and JSON's going to make one to json-ify it, and JSON is a type of transform of a hash.

However, JSON is usually done with XS, which means that the second traversal is faster, at least. That and JSON behavior is standardized.

```
use 5.016;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper ();
use JSON;

my $hash
    =  {
  'Foods' => {
    'fruits' => {
      'orange' => '1',
      'apple' => '2',
    },
    'Vegetables' => {
      'tomato' => '3',
      'carrot' => '1',
      'cabbage' => '2',
    }
  }
};

sub descend { 
    my ( $structure, $block ) = @_;
    my $res;
    while ( my ( $k, $v ) = each %$structure ) { 
        $block->( $structure, $k, $v );
        if ( ref( $v ) eq 'HASH' ) { 
            $res = descend( $v, $block );
        }
    }
    return $res;
}

my $new  = {};
my $curr = $new;

descend( $hash => sub { 
    my ( $lvl, $k, $v ) = @_;
    my $node = { text => $k };
    $curr->{children} //= [];
    push $curr->{children}, $node;

    if ( ref( $v ) eq 'HASH' ) { 
        $curr = $node;
    }
    else { 
        $node->{children} = { text => $v };
    }
});

# allow for the root-level special case, and retrieve the first child. 
$new = $new->{children}[0];

say Data::Dumper->Dump( [ $new ], [ '$new' ] );
say JSON->new->encode( $new );
```

Comment: thanks for the code, but it seems to not work properly to recognize the childs

Comment: @rahulsagar, that's exactly what `if ( ref( $v ) eq 'HASH' )` is branching on. If it's a hash, it's not a leaf node, otherwise it is and 'children' gets assigned one hash with one key 'text' pointing to the value, as you initially showed. I suspected it might be an issue on the javascript side where the nodes are similar, but we have an array of nodes for 'children' sometimes and a single node other times.